# how to switch between 2 different rigs for 1 model

Tags: mesh, rigging, edit-mode, bones, shape-keys

i have a character that transforms into a distorted creature using the shape key, the skeletal rig of the normal version has the skeletal mesh perfectly in its place however when i change the slider on the monster version for shape keys the bones stay where they are, i have tried ways to make the bones follow but apparently it does not work in that way, so i want to know if i can have 2 skeletal rigs for 1 model, 1 skeletal rig for the normal version and a skeletal rig for the monster version, here is some images
[image]

[image]

Comment: You could use two armatures. The bones must has unique names and you can switch between the armatures with the armature modifiers. -- But wouldn't it be easier to keep just one armature and scale the bones to create the monstrous growth?

Comment: yes it would be easier however during creating it i did not have that much time. it was for college